# Conversion of Image to XAML and improving the XAML Design Clarity

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, svg

I am trying to convert an image to XAML code. For this I am using "Potrace" and "SharpVectors". Potrace would convert the image to SVG(Scalar Vector Graphics) and SharpVectors would take the SVG File as input and gives XAML as output. The conversion is happening but the converted XAML design is not that clear. The Clarity of the image has been reduced. Any idea on improving the image clarity?

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "Potrace.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-s " +"test.bmp"+ " -o " + "test.svg"  ;
p.Start();
xamlcreator.Convert("test.svg");
```

xamlcreator is a function which is used from the SharpVectors dll.

Comment: I think the problem is the very first step. Converting a bitmap to a vector graphic. At this point you will almost always loose "image clarity"

Comment: I got to know that Inkscape is the tool which is used to convert Image to XAML. Inkscape uses the same technology i.e, Potrace to convert image to XAML. But, the image clarity is much better when compared to the output what I have got. Even Inkscape converts the image to SVG File. The clarity is good when Inkscape does that.

Comment: Have you tried exploring the settings Potrace.exe allows you to set? Have you called it with /? or --help ?

Comment: Yes @Samuel I have tried all the options.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't use Scaling and placement options:

```
 -P, --pagesize format      - page size (default is letter)
 -W, --width dim            - width of output image
 -H, --height dim           - height of output image
 -r, --resolution n[xn]     - resolution (in dpi) (dimension-based backends)
 -x, --scale n[xn]          - scaling factor (pixel-based backends)
 -S, --stretch n            - yresolution/xresolution
 -A, --rotate angle         - rotate counterclockwise by angle
 -M, --margin dim           - margin
 -L, --leftmargin dim       - left margin
 -R, --rightmargin dim      - right margin
 -T, --topmargin dim        - top margin
 -B, --bottommargin dim     - bottom margin
```

refer to [Potrace](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I have tried all the commands, still the quality is poor. All the above options would just set the position of output image. It does not improve the quality of the image. My guess is that "Tracing the image more than once can result in a better output". I am not sure and I do not know how to trace the image more than once.

Comment: Tracing multiple times could mean calling the tracer multiple times with the output of the previous run.

Comment: There is one more way. i,e the output which i am obtaining is in black and white regardless of the input. So the tracing is happening only for 2 colors. Any way to trace by taking more than 2 colors? Inkscape tool is taking the total number of colors to be traced in the input phase. So I guess that is the way. Any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: So using `Potrace.exe -r 1000` doesn't produce an image that is better quality than `Potrace.exe -r 70` ?

Comment: No @Mashton it does not give any better quality. Only the size of the image increases and decreases.

Comment: Any other ideas to increase the quality?